# restoring Thunderbird filters

Tags: thunderbird, imessagefilter

After saving `/home/user/.thunderbird` folder, I installed a new *Linux* system and restored the `.thunderbird` folder. It includes lots of filters for the *Inbox* so far filtering one email address, an *Imap* account.

In the new *Linux* system, the filters did not appear at the email address. Looking at the message filters, with the `Field Filters for:` one can choose between an email address and *Local Folders*. All my filters can be found at *Local Folders* and do no longer work on *Inbox*.

My intention now is, not to re-enter filter by filter, but find a way to make them work on the email address again instead of *Local Folders*. Do you have an advice for me?
I found the filter specification in `ImapMail/<provider>/msgFilterRules.dat`.

Why does *Thunderbird* think, the filters shall work on *Local Folders*?
How to make them work for the email address again?